# Using hooks with Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React and have just started using the context API as I have data that I need to access throughout my React Native application. My issue is with a TextField within one of my components. I have tried using both useState and useRef but I have not been able to type into the field since I started using the context API. Here is my code

```
const [associateNumber, setAssociateNumber] = useState('');

return (
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {({ login }) => (
    ...
    <TextInput
      secureTextEntry={true}
      label="Scan Badge"
      value={associateNumber}
      onChangeText={text => {
        setAssociateNumber(text);
      }}
      onSubmitEditing={() => {
        login(value);
      }}
      clearTextOnFocus={true}
    />
    ...
  })
</AppContext.Consumer>
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add this to text input

```
onChange={(e)=>setAssociateNumber(e.target.value)}
```

and delete onChangeText

Comment: This solution doesn't apply to React Native, and doesn't make much sense in React either.